# Facebook4J OAuth failing

Tags: java, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook4j

I am trying to search for public items using Facebook4J, I understad I need an appId AND appSecret which I have, the app token is the these two with a pipe symbol between them (as I understand). I can not understand why I am gett an OAuthError , Please see my code below and precise error code.

```
    facebook4j.conf.ConfigurationBuilder fac = new facebook4j.conf.ConfigurationBuilder();

    fac.setDebugEnabled(true)
      .setOAuthAppId("appId")
      .setOAuthAppSecret("appSecret")
      .setOAuthPermissions("email,publish_stream");
    fac.setOAuthAccessToken(accessToken);
    FacebookFactory ff = new FacebookFactory(fac.build());
   Facebook facebook = ff.getInstance();

   ResponseList<JSONObject> results = facebook.search("%whatever");
```

This is the following error code I get. Error code one seems to be unknown API???

Exception in thread "main" message - An unknown error has occurred.
code - 1
Relevant information for error recovery can be found on the Facebook Developers Document:
    https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/#errors

```
FacebookException{statusCode=500, errorType='OAuthException', errorMessage='An unknown error has occurred.', errorCode=1, errorSubcode=-1, version=2.4.2}
    at facebook4j.internal.http.HttpClientImpl.request(HttpClientImpl.java:179)
    at facebook4j.internal.http.HttpClientWrapper.request(HttpClientWrapper.java:61)
    at facebook4j.internal.http.HttpClientWrapper.get(HttpClientWrapper.java:89)
    at facebook4j.FacebookImpl.get(FacebookImpl.java:2742)
    at facebook4j.FacebookImpl.search(FacebookImpl.java:2337)
    at facebook4j.FacebookImpl.search(FacebookImpl.java:2332)
    at Main.facebook4JRequest(Main.java:37)
    at Main.main(Main.java:15)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using the below code it worked for me.

```
Facebook facebook = new FacebookFactory().getInstance();  
facebook.setOAuthAppId("XXXXXX", "XXXXXXXXXXXX");
String accessTokenString = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
AccessToken at = new AccessToken(accessTokenString);
facebook.setOAuthAccessToken(at);

ResponseList<Post> feeds = facebook.getPosts("%whatever", new Reading().limit(80));
```

Comment: I have it working now. When I use the temp access token from the graph explorer I am getting X amount of data from a search, although when I use the access token I obtain from my App ID and secret I get Y. Where X > Y for the exactly the same search. why?